# Html Animation different in Google Chrome vs Edge. Autoplay work around help for animation?

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome, microsoft-edge

I have created an animation that I'm using for an intro video but, recording it is nearly impossible in Google Chrome because of the auto play policy.

If auto play could work for an offline html file than that would solve my issue. However, in Edge the autoplay works but the animation is completely different than from what I want.

I've saved a w3schools project to show mine: https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=G6QHCHUPIK9B

The images are different than what I'm using in my offline project.

I'd like to have the animation that Google Chrome is giving but with autoplay working every time.

One idea I had was to manually start the videos and then have the animation move them off the screen however the starting point would be off from what I want.

Maybe another browser is what I should try using? I don't know what the best option would be.

Comment: It can be easier to put the code from the link into a html document and try opening in a browser to view the result.

Answer (score 0):

For Google Chrome to change the autoplay policy I found you can go to: chrome://flags/#autoplay-policy and from there disable it (right at the top).

This will work as a temporary fix but I'm still curious about trying to max the animations the same between Google Chrome and Edge.